# Process terminated with status 1

Tags: c++, c, codeblocks

I'm working on code::blocks 10.05 and i want to read an TIFF image file in c/c++. For this I'm using LibTiff library so I'm including tiffio.h as an header file. Now when i compile, i get an error "process terminated with status 1. And i have also given full path of the library to the Linker.

The entire build log says:

Linking console executable: bin\Release\tifff.exe

mingw32-g++.exe: E:\Image: No such file or directory

mingw32-g++.exe: Transforms\Libraries\tifflib\libs\libtiff: No such file or directory

Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 8 seconds)
0 errors, 0 warnings

Comment: The linker is not finding the libraries.  Where is the file "tifflib\libs\libtiff" in your directory tree?

Comment: Thx alot for responding to my query and my file is in E:\Image_Transforms\Libraries\tifflib\libs\libtiff...and its an library containg header files..please help me out...

Answer (score 2):

Given the output that you gave, it seems like the linker, as @gcbenison said, is not finding libtiff.

What's more, given that it shows two lines of output, I'd suppose that your libtiff library is inside "E:\Image Transforms\Libraries\tifflib\libs\libtiff", right?

Well, Code::Blocks [doesn't seem to like](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Debugging_with_Code%3a%3aBlocks) paths with spaces. So try to rename "Image Transforms" to "Image_Transforms", correct the library path in Code::Blocks and try again.

**EDIT**: Elaborated on the answer

Also, do make sure so you can have the compiled libtiff library. I downloaded [libtiff 3.8.2-1.exe](http://ufpr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/gnuwin32/tiff/3.8.2-1/tiff-3.8.2-1.exe) from the [GNUwin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/tiff.htm) project to test and it worked flawlessly. Try to do the following to build a minimally working program that uses libtiff:

- Install the aforementioned libtiff library in C:\GnuWin32. After you install it, you will have many directories inside that one, including bin, contrib, doc, include, lib, among others;
- Create a new **Console application** project in Code::Blocks;
- Tell Code::Blocks it is a C program;
- After your project is created, access the "Build options" dialog by clicking on your project and then clicking "Build options...";
- In the "Linker settings" tab, "Link libraries" frame, click "Add" and add libtiff.dll.a. If you installed libtiff in C:\GnuWin32, the library you want will be C:\GnuWin32\lib\libtiff.dll.a;
- In the "Search directories" tab, you will:

  - Select the "Compiler" tab and add "C:\GnuWin32\include" to it;
  - Select the "Linker" tab and add "C:\GnuWin32\lib" to it;
- The click "Ok" in the "Build options" dialog, as everything should be ok by now.

You could try to build your program now an see if the build succeeds. I used the first example in [Graphics programming with libtiff, Part 2](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-libtiff2/) as a test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <tiffio.h>
int main()
{
  TIFF *output;
  uint32 width, height;
  char *raster;
  printf("Trying to write TIFF...\n");
  if((output = TIFFOpen("output.tif", "w")) == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open outgoing image\n");
    exit(42);
  }
  width = 42;
  height = 42;
  if((raster = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * width * height * 3)) == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate enough memory\n");
    exit(42);
  }
  TIFFSetField(output, TIFFTAG_IMAGEWIDTH, width);
  TIFFSetField(output, TIFFTAG_IMAGELENGTH, height);
  TIFFSetField(output, TIFFTAG_COMPRESSION, COMPRESSION_DEFLATE);
  TIFFSetField(output, TIFFTAG_PLANARCONFIG, PLANARCONFIG_CONTIG);
  TIFFSetField(output, TIFFTAG_PHOTOMETRIC, PHOTOMETRIC_RGB);
  TIFFSetField(output, TIFFTAG_BITSPERSAMPLE, 8);
  TIFFSetField(output, TIFFTAG_SAMPLESPERPIXEL, 3);
  if(TIFFWriteEncodedStrip(output, 0, raster, width * height * 3) == 0){
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not write image\n");
    exit(42);
  }
  TIFFClose(output);
  printf("TIFF written successfully.\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Now try to build (Ctrl+F9) and run your program. I followed the steps I mentioned above and got my program compiling and working.

For the build, Code::Blocks' output was (I named my program libtiff):

```
-------------- Build: Debug in libtiff ---------------

Compiling: main.c
Linking console executable: bin\Debug\libtiff.exe
Output size is 27,93 KB
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
0 errors, 0 warnings
```

For the run, it output:

```
Trying to write TIFF...
TIFF written successfully.

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.125 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: Thxx alot sir.. i have changed it to image_transforms but still it shows the same error. Also in project\properties\libraries after setting the above path for an unknown library, when i compile it gives an libfinder error saying "didn't found configuration for libraries and asks me to go to the detection dialog..Now when i went to dialog it shows me missing definitions for the above path and gives an option to download this missing definition but when i try downloading this code::block is not responding..:(:( please help me out...somebody please respond to this query...thx in advance..

Comment: Thxx alot sir its been a gr8 help.After following all the steps as u mentioned & implementing ur sample code.Its build is successful bt wen i run it,it gives an error saying "Program cant start bcoz libtiff3.dll is missing" & build log says "Checking for existence: E:\CBoutput\Tiffs\bin\Debug\Tiffs.exe
Executing: "C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks/cb_console_runner.exe" "E:\CBoutput\Tiffs\bin\Debug\Tiffs.exe"  (in E:\CBoutput\Tiffs\.)
Process terminated with status -1073741510 (2 minutes, 20 seconds)
" & once again thx a lot for helping me out.for d last time jus help me fixng up this problem.

Comment: What about copying E:\CBoutput\Tiffs\bin\Debug\Tiffs.exe to C:\GnuWin32\bin just to test? That's where libtiff3.dll should be located, supposing you installed libtiff in C:\GnuWin32.

Comment: Hello sir.Sory for the late rep as my internet was down due to some tech.fault.As u said i moved to C:\GnuWin32.Again it gets compiled properly bt whn i try to run it gves an err "The application was unable to start correctly" & build log says:Checking for existence: C:\Program Files(x86)\GnuWin32\bin\CBoutput\png1\bin\Debug\png1.exe
Executing:"C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks/cb_console_runner.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\CBoutput\png1\bin\Debug\png1.exe"  (in C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\CBoutput\png1\.)
Process terminated with status -1073741510 (3 minutes, 28 seconds)